# The pi as a mobile, off-grid outdoor device

Tags: usb, hardware, software-development, software-recommendation

How can current Raspberry Pi **power** and **display** technology be used to create a practical, outdoor computer for light weight text editing or programming off-the-grid and in strong ambient light conditions?

Sub-optimal solutions I've identified (with trade offs):

- [Raspberry pi w/ pixel qi ambient light display](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1303) (not very rugged - no casing)
- [Raspberry pi w/ e-ink display](http://makerflux.com/kindle-used-as-an-e-paper-display-for-the-raspberry-pi/) and solar panel power supply (e-ink too slow...)
- Raspberry pi w/ LCD display (poor ambient light visibility...)

Comment: I think the specification misses some important points. Text editing and "programming" (which is quite wide) could be done more easily with any tablet computer. Unless you need the hardware platform of the Pi or GPIO (or something that the Pi offers over a Pad) I do not really see the point of picking a Pi.

Comment: @Ghanima - ambient light poses a unique challenge to outdoor displaying. Not many off-the-shelf pad's have e-paper or transreflective surface technology ([Hydra T3](http://www.inhand.com/why-use-the-hydra-t3-rugged-pc-tablet-from-inhand/) is the only contender I've been able to find). With a pi I can essentially build "my own pad" with a more desirable display.

Comment: The pi is not a good choice for this.  Its heritage is line-powered set-top boxes so it lacks the thrifty just-as-much-as-needed power management of tablet/phone systems intended for battery-powered use.

Comment: Thanks, everyone is right - this is a job for a tablet. I just bought an Onyx Boox M96 with a bluetooth keyboard. Runner up was the Sol Computer Windows Tablet (too expensive and outdated).

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather have a nice ultrabook for this kind of purpose, but of course they are quite a bit more expensive. The pi only consumes a few watts of power, but I'm guessing a display will add 5-10 more, so relative to an ultrabook or tablet it will be not very efficient considering all you get is a single 700 Mhz core.

You'll need a substantial power bank if you want to use it for more than 4 hours.  Those generally don't have much of a meter (e.g. 4 leds), which is awkward since the pi won't be able to tell how much is left; either you just let it run out (not very conducive to programming -- you'll lose everything since your last save), or you guesstimate, reducing your productive time.<sup>1</sup>

I've seen a lot of things [like this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1952418207/all-in-one-raspberry-pi-case) around; here's [another one](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/pitouch/pitablet-a-raspberry-pi-powered-tablet-starting-at?ref=nav_search).  That's just searching kickstarter.  But as you can see, you're likely going to end up with something fairly bulky.

By the time you add up the cost of the pi, the screen, the power bank, the keyboard, etc., you're not saving much money vs. a decent tablet w/ keyboard, which will be much more practical for this, I think.  Unfortunately your choice of operating systems there is very limited -- e.g., you can't program on android.

---

<sup>1. Note that you can detect the voltage drop as the battery dies, but this means some more additions to the board.  I imagine the simplest thing would be to attach a cheap voltmeter ([e.g.](http://www.gearbest.com/development-boards/pp_135810.html)), but there are also solutions that would allow you to [feed this information to the pi itself](http://raspi.tv/tag/raspberry-pi-monitoring-its-own-battery-voltage).</sup>

Comment: Paragraph 1 & 2 are great points well received. Ambient outdoor lighting is still the major downside to your suggestions though. This is why I sought the Pixel Qi display as one of my sub-optimal solutions.

Comment: I actually recommend against this *unless* you already have a pi and are aware of and comfortable with its limitations -- I don't think I would ever do it myself, but if I were, these are the things I'd start considering (power, tracking power consumption, casing).  I've added a footnote WRT tracking power consumption.